# How to pre-load a fragment before showing?

Tags: android, fragment

In my activity I have several fullscreen fragments, each of them downloads some data from web (using an async task) and shows them to the user. The fragments are showed one at a time.

To be more specific, each of the fragment readings some urls from a sqlite database, and fetch the content before showing them in a list, if that matters. The data loading tasks can be done in the OnCreate() function.

I would like to preload all the fragment (at least starting the downloading), when I show a splash screen. Pretty much like a viewpager preload its fragments.

I am wondering how to achieve this? I tried initialize/create all the fragments in the OnCreate() function of my activity, hoping the OnCreate() of fragments could be called earlier, but the OnCreate() and OnCreateView() function of the fragments are not called until a fragment is about to show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to separate your model (the data which is downloaded) from your view (the fragments). One way to do this is to start the downloading AsyncTasks in your activity, rather than starting them in each fragment. Then when the fragments are eventually displayed they can show the data which has been downloaded (or a spinner or some other indication that the download process is still executing).

Comment: That is true, and I thought about it. The reason I am not doing it now is that, I have several fragments attached to the activity, each of them host some data. If I put all the data download/update task into the activity, it ends up to a cumbersome activity, and also create very strong couple between my hosting activity and fragments, which defeat the purpose of fragments to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

> Fragment's onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().

So your solution to this problem is initialize or create or do your stuffs which you want to preload before fragments are created, inside your `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated(Bundle)`

see [documents for fragment's lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

The earliest pace you can start loading is either in a static singleton or in the [Application Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing is the following, (1) add all the fragments into the container. So they (and their view) will be created and initialized. (2) hide those not in use and only show the one I would like the user to see. (3) use FragmentTrasaction.show()/FragmentTrasaction.hide() to manipulate the visibility instead of FragmentTrasaction.add() or FragmentTrasaction.replace().

If you following this approach, be warn that all the fragments will be cached in memory. But the benefit is the switch between fragment will be fast and efficient.

Comment: "Fast" yes, "efficient" no

Comment: @MartinKonecny, I know what you are saying. But in my app, the user will flip between all fragments fairly frequently. I don't want them to wait for the data to load. Do you have a more efficient way to implement the logic?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first step? What do you means by 'add all the fragments into the container'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and then I used this method, suppose we are having an EditText in the fragment, then we can use codes like this

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //this method allows you to input or instantiate fragments before showing this to an activity conidering id is "editTextEditProfileFirstName"
    EditText firstName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextEditProfileFirstName);

    firstName.setText("This is my first name", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```