# How to create a more lighweight fragment?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I've a navigation drawer for changing fragments in my MainActivity, there is a fragment that has many views inside it and I need to make it more lightweight.

The problem is that by the time Navigation Drawer hides, the Fragment Transaction hasn't happened yet. My Fragment has 3 CardViews with several EditText inside it, all of them with attached TextWatchers, for updating the text in other views. I've tried to remove as many views as posible, and still not big difference, but if I remove half of the views can notice the change, so I believe that is the problem. Is there any way to make a Fragment more lighweight without removing views?

My NavigationDrawer includes this menu and a header:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment_selector"
            android:title="@string/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icons8_home_96px">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/conteo_fragment_selector"
            android:title="@string/review"
            android:icon="@drawable/icons8_banknotes_96px">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/exchange_fragment_selector"
            android:title="@string/exchange"
            android:icon="@drawable/icons8_exchange_96px">
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

For replacing the fragments, the code I'm using looks like this, I used 2 Runnables so I can run the code in any order I want:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        final int id = item.getItemId();

        Runnable closeDrawerLayoutRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

        };

        Runnable replaceFragmentRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home_fragment_selector:
                        FragmentTransaction ftHome = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ftHome.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,0);
                        ftHome.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,home);
                        ftHome.commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.count_fragment_selector:
                        FragmentTransaction ftCount = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ftCount.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,0);
                        ftCount.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,count);
                        ftCount.commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.exchange_fragment_selector:
                        FragmentTransaction ftExchange = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ftExchange.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,0);
                        ftExchamge.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,exchange);
                        ftExchange.commit();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(closeDrawerLayoutRunnable,250);
        mHandler.postDelayed(replaceFragmentRunnable,50);
        return true;
    }
```

With the other two fragments there's no problem at all, but with count fragment, rest of the code is pretty much the same:

```
TextWatcher generiTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(s.hashCode()==Edit1000.getText().hashCode()){
                    if(s.toString().equals("")){cup1000 = 0;}
                    else {cup1000 = Float.valueOf(s.toString());}
                    //Same procedure for rest of the EditText, so I can use same TextWatcher instead of using a new one
                }
};

//There is 21 of this EditText with its own findViewById() and TextWatcher attachment
Edit1000 = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_1000);
cupEdit1000.addTextChangedListener(generiTextWatcher);
//.. So on
```

I've noticed that if I replace this Fragment with another one, and then replace de the other again with this first one, the transaction is very fast, I don't know what can it be

Comment: Usually having a more UI-Heavy view does not cause the issues you are discussing except in a few circumstances. Can you post some code of the drawer, drawer adapter, and the fragment you mentioned so we can get a better idea of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this idea:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25671367/11456044

I know this is not an efficient way, but it is very very fast, it solved my problem, at least temporarily